# WPF Datagrid bound to Linq to SQL DataContext but initialized by data external to database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have a case in which data external to a database is displayed in a WPF DataGrid.  Currently, the data comes in as an ObservableCollection of type T, where each T is a class that models a database table row.

Some of the data may already exist in the database table, but some may be new and will not be stored in the database.  The DataGrid provides a way of editing/adding new items to the table and viewing those items that have already been analyzed (they exist in the database).

So, here's my problem - I would like to use Linq to SQL to create a dbml datacontext on the table for CRUD operations.  However, the data coming in when the grid is loaded is not from the database.  I check the database for items that match what's in the ObservableCollection and highlight them in the grid to indicate that they already exist, and to highlight those items in the ObservableCollection that are not in the database.  There is a primary key on the database table.

My first inclination is to bind the DataGrid to the ObservableCollection on the load operation, and then switch the context to the dbml datacontext after the grid is loaded.  From that point forward, I would expect the CRUD operations to make their way to the database.

Is this a reasonable approach?  I bet there's something better and I would appreciate feedback on how best to tackle this problem.  Thanks

Comment: Your databound collection should contain ViewModels that wrap Business Objects. That should give you all the flexibility you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let's split things up for clarity... we have a UI and we have some data in a database. First, we need to create some kind of data object class that contains all of the properties that the users want to edit in the UI.

Then we need a data object that reflects the columns and tables in the database... this can be an object oriented object that contains values from multiple tables, or it can be one or more flat object(s), each mapping one table.

Usually, these two data type objects are the same object, eg. we can usually create one data type class to fulfil both requirements. However, it is perfectly fine to have different objects and copy the data from one to the other in a view model.

Now if you have a data type class that has more properties than there are related columns in the database tables, that's not a problem. It is common to have 'empty properties' after filling these objects from the database... the empty properties can then be filled in a view model with data from anywhere else and displayed along with the database data.

Once you have a data type, or model class, then you can declare an `ObservableCollection` of that type and once filled, `Bind` that to the `ItemsSource` property of any collection control. The main thing is that you fulfil your data and UI requirements; you save the right data in the database; you show the right information in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.  I understand all that; however, I wish to take advantage of the CRUD functionality obtained from the dbml plumbing.  Ideally the DataGrid would be hooked up to the DataContext of the dbml from the start.

So, here's where I'm headed:  bring in the external data as a LINQ table having the exact same schema as the dbml database table.  Then, do a left outer join, with the incoming table as the first table, against the database table via a linq query on the context and use the results set for initializing the DataGrid ItemsSource.  No context changed needed. I'll let you know if that works.

It's much simpler than I had envisioned.  Initially I had the misconception that the DataGrid had to be bound to the dbml datacontext in order to take advantage of the CRUD features of the datacontext.  Not so.  The DataGrid can be bound to the incoming data, which is not in the database, via the ObserveableCollection.  Edits, inserts, deletes at the DataGrid can be passed on to a dbml datacontext through the appropriate event handlers.

The item in the datacontext is matched with the edited item in the grid through a primary key on the db table - the incoming ObservableCollection (OC) items are assigned the primary key prior to the binding of the OC to the datagrid.

When this current task of mine is wrapped up, I'll post some sample code (give me a few days).

Bill